# landscape with \addtolength messing up location of page number

Tags: tables, landscape

I want a page number in the normal position but when I combine my methodology of margin stretching with `landscape` then the page number moves to the right ***a lot***.

Note that "TABLE GOES HERE" is actually a `longtable` table in my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}



\clearpage
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.45in}
\begin{landscape}
LONGTABLE TABLE GOES HERE
\end{landscape}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-4in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0.45in}
\clearpage 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar (1) Unfortunately I do not understand your advice. (2) Perhaps it does add extra area outside of the page, but my landscape tables fit *perfectly* in the center of the page. I chose not to put the whole table's code into my post though.

Comment: @HarishKumar I am using `longtable` inside the `landscape` in my actual code.

Comment: `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to your preamble to see what is happening.

Comment: If you are using `longtable`, why you have to increase the `textwidth`. Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: I increase `textwidth` to make it fit on one page and stop pagebreak. I then use `\hoffset` to make it go more tot he left because otherwise it just goes off the right side of the page. If I do not increase my margins then the longtable will `pagebreak` off the last 2 lines. I use `longtable` even for tables that are 1 page long because I make 30 tables for my project so it is easier to just use `longtable` for all of them instead of alternating between other types of table.

Comment: Does using `\addtolength{\textwidth}{2\baselineskip}` help?

Comment: @HarishKumar Do I delete my existing `\addtolength` commands and replace it with one instance of `\addtolength{\textwidth}{2\baselineskip}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `4in` to `\textwidth` takes you out of the page, as already noted in the comments. But probably this is only an artifact of the MWE, the original document might use much larger margins/marginpar.

The following hack undoes the layout changes for the footer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\footfix}{%
  \let\orig@oddfoot\@oddfoot
  \renewcommand*{\@oddfoot}{%
    \hspace{.45in}%
    \hbox to\dimexpr\textwidth-4in\relax{\orig@oddfoot}%
    \hfil
  }%
  \let\orig@evenfoot\@evenfoot
  \renewcommand*{\@evenfoot}{%
    \hspace{.45in}%
    \hbox to\dimexpr\textwidth-4in\relax{\orig@evenfoot}%
    \hfil
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.45in}
\begin{landscape}
\footfix
TABLE GOES HERE
\newpage
Second page
\end{landscape}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-4in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0.45in}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```